# Как заменить значения NaN столбца значениями из другого фрейма данных по ключу?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, машинное-обучение

У меня есть два фрейма данных. В первом содержится полная информация о фильмах, а второй, с пропусками NaN в столбце наименований фильмов:

[image: Часть датафрейма с пропусками, которые надо заполнить]

А в первом фрейме содержится полная информация о фильмах. Как можно взять наименование фильма из основного полного фрейма по ключу 'movieId' и вставить его в неполный с пропусками?

Вот [ссылка на файлы](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BEsSjYhid7jsiA?w=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv", index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv", index_col=0)

res = df2.drop(columns="title").merge(df1[["movieId", "title"]].drop_duplicates())
```

результат:

```
In [317]: res
Out[317]:
       userId  movieId  rating                                title
0           1      858     5.0                 Sleepless in Seattle
1           3      858     4.0                 Sleepless in Seattle
2           5      858     5.0                 Sleepless in Seattle
3          12      858     4.0                 Sleepless in Seattle
4          20      858     4.5                 Sleepless in Seattle
...       ...      ...     ...                                  ...
13227    1273     8373     5.0  Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen
13228    1274     8373     5.0  Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen
13229    1275     8373     5.0  Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen
13230    1276     8373     4.0  Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen
13231    1277     8373     NaN  Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen

[13232 rows x 4 columns]
```

**NOTE:** на будущее - в подобных вопросах следует всегда приводить в вопросе [воспроизводимый пример входных данных (**в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл**) и **то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Учту в следующий раз. В вашем решении ошибка `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. Вот ссылка на файлы: (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BEsSjYhid7jsiA?w=1)

Comment: @АлександрКоротких, решение зависит от данных - в ваших данных были дубликаты строк, поэтому первое решение не работало. Сейчас ответ проверен на предоставленном примере данных.